# ListView from SQLite showing up weirdly

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I'm trying to populate a ListView from a SQLite database, but the `Log` is showing: `com.example.apple.bookshelf.Book@3d3844f2`. Gradle builds without any errors or warnings.

Any idea what's wrong?

My database setup has fields called `id`, `title`, `author`, `collection` and `body`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.apple.bookshelf;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView authorsListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        authorsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.authors_list_view);
        String[] authors = {"Christie, Agatha","Conan Doyle, Arthur","James, M.R."};

        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        List bookList = db.getAllBooks();

        /*
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bookList);

        authorsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        */

        Log.i("test", bookList.toString());

    }

}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.apple.bookshelf;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "books.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "books";

    public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<String> getAllBooks() {

        List bookList = new ArrayList();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Book book = new Book();
                book.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                bookList.add(book);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return bookList;

    }
}
```

**Book.java**

```
package com.example.apple.bookshelf;

public class Book {

    int id;
    String title;
    String author;
    String collection;
    String body;

    public Book() {

    }

    public Book(int id, String title, String author, String collection, String body) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.collection = collection;
        this.body = body;
    }

    // getters

    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return this.author;
    }

    public String getCollection() {
        return this.collection;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return this.body;
    }

    // setters

    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setCollection(String collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need custom adapter to populate listview using object with multiple arguments. Your `ArrayAdapter` is for single object like String. All what you need to do is create an adapter item (layout resource for one item) and use it in class extending ArrayAdapter. [Here's](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter) an example, how you should do this.

Answer (score 0):

In `getAllBooks`, instead of creating a String list you are creating and returning a Book list. Thus, when in `MainActivity`, you are actually printing string representations of the Book objects. To fix this, you need to actually put Strings into the list in `getAllBooks`. Also, please always use typed lists (specify the type of the list elements in the diamonds, e.g. `List<Book>`or `List<String>`) so such mistakes are caught by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What would I have to change in `getAllBooks` to create a String list instead of a Book list?

Comment: @Sebastian Instead of adding the books to the list, you need to add strings to the list. But judging from your code, you actually do want books in that list, right? If that's the case, then everything is correct - you do have books in there. It's just that it you want to have something meaningful when calling toString, you need to create a method called toString in Book.java and return a string there

Comment: @Sebastian Yet still, I would advise you to supply diamond types to all List instances in your code, no matter if Book or String or whatever you put in there.

Comment: `List<String> bookList = new ArrayList();
Cursor cursor = ...

if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
 do {
  bookList.add(cursor.getString(1)); //this will create a list of books titles
 } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}`

Comment: @grabarz121 thanks for this. How would I reference other database fields like `author`?

Comment: That's only returning the `title` field but I can't see where that was specified...

Comment: Link in my comment to your first post :) Above, not here.

Comment: Ah, I got it, it's the `(1)` - if you wanna write up an answer with that code snippet I'll include it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Short the line `bookList.add(book);` assigns the Book object as a string to the respective element, rather than a member/property of the Book, hence the @.... which is a reference to the instance of the Book.

You could use `bookList.add(book.addAuthor);`. However, the problem is that the using the List, say to update a listed book by clicking it becomes problematic because all the ListViews knows about is the text being displayed and the position within the list.

In short using an Array of strings as the source for the adapter makes it hard/problematic to get back to the original data held in the database. You only have the position of the String or the String itself as a reference. The position cannot be used to reliably determine a rows's rowid, which is the arguably the best value for accessing a single row of a table. Position's start at 0, rowid's at 1; rowid's are not guaranteed to increment by 1, position will, rows can be deleted leaving gaps; data may not be ordered according to rowid.

You can actually pass a list of **Books** to the adapter. There as a small issue though that an `ArrayAdapter` uses the object's `toString` method to retrieve the text from the respective array element. Supplying a `toString` method for the object allows you to control what is displayed. However, within the onClickListener, as an example, the position correlates to the Book in the list of Books from which you can then access other information, such as the **id**.

So if you were to add the following to your Book class, it would be able to display Author and Title :-

```
public String toString() {
   return this.author + ", " + this.title;
}
```

You'd also need to change the `getAllBooks` method to return an array of Books :-

```
public Book[] getAllBooks() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWriteableDatabse();
    Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    Book[] books = new Book[csr.getCount()];
    while (csr.moveToNext) {
        books[csr.getPosition] = new Book(
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                "","");
    }
    csr.close;
    return books;
}
```

*Note I'd suggest not using hard-coded offsets, but to instead use the Cursor's `getColumnIndex` method e.g. assuming that the column name for the first column (the id) is **_id**, then rather than `Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))`, you could use :-

```
Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("_id"))
```

Assuming that the ID column is an alias for the **rowid** i.e. it has been defined as `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` (where column_name only represent that actual column name used) then the value could exceed what an **int** can hold so you should really be using long. You do not need to use Parse and getString to extract as value, Cursor has various get methods such as getInt and getlong.

As such ideally you should be using :-

```
cursor.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("column_name"));
```

along with changing the Book class to use `long id`;

You would also need to change the adapter code :-

```
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    Book[] booklist = getAllBooks();

    ArrayAdapter<Book[]> arrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bookList);

    authorsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

---

An alternative would be to use a **CursorAdapter**.

You could do :-

```
    Cursor csr = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,"*,rowid AS _id",null,null,null,null,null);
    SimpleCursorAdpater sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
        csr,
        new String[]{"title_column"},
        new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
        0
    );
    authorsListView.setAdapater(sca);
```

Where title_column would be the name of the title column or authour column.

You could also use :-

```
    Cursor csr = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,"*,rowid AS _id",null,null,null,null,null);
    SimpleCursorAdpater sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
        csr,
        new String[]{"title_column","author_column"},
        new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},
        0
    );
    authorsListView.setAdapater(sca);
```

And both the title and the author would appear in the list. Again using the actual column names rather than the made up column names.

Note the above is untested, so there may be the odd error or typo.

I'd personally add a specific method to extract all rows to the DatabaseHelper Class e.g. getAllBooks which could be:-

```
public Cursor getAllBooks() {
    return this.getWriteableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME,"*,rowid AS _id",null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Note! **`"*, rowid AS _id"`**, assumes that your **id** column is not named **_id**. If your **id** column is named **_id** then the 2nd parameter to the `query` method could be null. A CursorAdapter requires that there is a column named **_id**. This is then passed to the `onItemClickListener` and also the `onItemLongClickListener`.